# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined react

Tags: reactjs

I have been working on a todo list in react, and ran into a problem I've been having trouble figuring out. I managed to get the todo list to dynamically update my array state, but having a little problem with displaying it. Here is the code: (https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-curran-fldtg?fontsize=14). At the top I give a brief explanation of what everything does. The problem area is at the bottom, this line of code:

```
const DisplayTasks = () => {
  const { tasksarray } = this.state;
  return (
    <ol>
      {tasksarray.map(eachTask => (
        <li>{eachTask}</li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};
```

I'm able to get the app working the way I want it by deleting the DisplayTask component and putting the ol code in render() like so:

```
  render() {                                                      
  const { tasksarray } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <GetTask task={this.inputTask} />
      <ol>
        {tasksarray.map(eachTask => (
          <li>{eachTask}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm wondering why I get TypeError Cannot read property 'state' of undefined when I try to do it as a component, and if there's a way to make it work as a component rather than directly in render()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access `this.state` in Functional Component.

In react, the parent component can pass data to the child using the `props` like below

```
 const DisplayTasks = ({tasks}) => {
    return (
     <ol>
      {tasks.map((task, index) => <li key={index}>{task}</li>)}
     </ol>
    );
 };


 render() {                                                      
   return (
     <div>
       <GetTask task={this.inputTask} />
       <DisplayTasks tasks={this.state.tasksarray} />
     </div>
   );
 }
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the answer.